# Display iTerm on screen with cursor [or Active Screen]

Tags: macos, iterm2

I always have iTerm running in the background, and use a hotkey to show/hide it when needed, which works great when using only one screen.

Now, with two screens, I notice that with the option to have it appear with the "Screen with Cursor", the first time I press the hotkey, it appears on the screen with the cursor (first screen), but when I hide it, move the cursor to another screen (second screen) and press the hotkey again, it appears on the first screen and not the second one.

Is there another setting that I might be missing to have work properly?

Comment: This question may be better suited somewhere like https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you @dmoz. I just asked there as well.